# Why is there a low pass filter in a DSBSC demodulator?

Tags: analog, communication, fourier

In analog communication, DSBSC (double side band suppressed carrier) is way of modulating signal.

In this the carrier is simply multiplied with the message signal.

At the demodulator, the carrier is multiplied back which gives the message signal back.

[image]

- The first signal is my message signal
- The second is the modulated signal
- The third is the demodulated signal i.e I can get the msg by simply tracking the peak voltages

Now the demodulation process seems to be complete but the part that I am missing is a low pass filtee at demodulator.  Why is it required?  I have my signal back. Why should I pass it through a low pass filter? All the books have the filter.

Please explain why the low pass filter is required after the demodulator.

Matlab code

---

```matlab
t=0:1e-4:30;
f=5;
y=sind(2*pi*f*t);
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(t,y)
hold on
yline(0)
xline(0.2)
ylim([-2 2])
hold off
subplot(3,1,2)
y1=sind(2*pi*100*t);

y3=y1.*y;

plot(t,y3)
hold on

yline(0)
hold off
subplot(3,1,3)

y4=y3.*sind(2*pi*100*t);

plot(t,y4)
hold on
ylim([-2 2])
plot(t,y);
hold off
```

Comment: which LPF where?

Comment: You tell me, whether the first graph is the same as the third graph.

Comment: LPF at demodulator

Comment: @user253751 no it just seams to be scaled to 2 .

Comment: It looks like it has some high frequency content in it too @NewtonNadar

Comment: @Colin But the graph are same.I mean the peaks

Comment: @NewtonNadar, no, they're not, the top one is a fairly clean sinusoid, the bottom one is a sinusoid with some modulation superimposed on it, unless we're looking at different images.

Comment: Yes Sir, The third wave is the wave after demodulating. \ i.e. m(t)*sin(fc*t)

Comment: 'Tracking the peak voltages... ". What circuit would you use to do that? (Hint - its a filter).

Comment: Thrid graph has two lines; a blue line and a red line. the red line is the output of the LPF. blue line is the input to the LPF.

Comment: But I can get it by simply a sample and hold circuit ,with proper RC combination or If I have a micro controller I would track those peak values .Then why a low pass filter? Please explain @AJN

Comment: RC combination you speak of, *is* a low pass filter. "*If I have a micro controller I would track those peak values*". Well, if you had a fast enough micro controller, you could have done the multiplication also in it. A separate demodulator (`y4 = y3 .* sin...`) would also not be required! [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_down_converter)

Comment: @NewtonNadar Why does the code use `sind` instead of `sin` ? `sind` is very likely the wrong function to use in this context.

Comment: @NewtonNadar Would you say that tracking the peaks is... a type of low-pass filter?

Comment: @NewtonNadar a peak detector would not work for suppressed carrier. During the negative cycles, the message is sitting in the valleys, not the peaks! Look carefully at the blue line in the third graph, particularly between 6 and 12 on the x axis.

Comment: Thank you understood the problem with peak detector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Third is the demodulated signal i.e I can get the msg by simply
> tracking the peak voltages

A simple peak detector will rise to the top-most peak and stay there (the maximum voltage peak of the original message will be captured). So you must modify the simple peak detector so that it decays toward zero as time passes, else the original message bottom-most voltage won't be captured....this is starting to look like a low-pass filter. Another problem with peak detectors is their poor performance where the demodulated message includes noise.

Yes, the original message can be reconstructed by sampling the demodulated signal *at the moment of each +ve peak*. This method requires knowledge of carrier phase, and requires a phase-locked-loop to track 2xcarrier frequency.
OP has used this method, since the demodulator magically has used a re-constructed carrier frequency that is phase-locked to the modulator carrier frequency:

```
y4=y3.*sind(2*pi*100*t);
```

This phase-locking method has problems: for example, if the message is at zero, there's no carrier for the phase-locked-loop to track. In stereo FM, this problem is avoided by always transmitting a little bit of 19 kHz subcarrier (by adding a DC offset to the modulator's message signal). But this is no longer pure DSB-SC. And you still have the problem of poor noise performance, if you don't add a low-pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

The third graph contains the demodulated signal (blue line). It clearly has two frequencies in it: a low frequency (of the original message signal) and a high frequency.

**One method** to get the low frequency message signal out of the combined singal is to use a low pass filter.

A peak detector would **not** work with suppressed carrier signal since you need a *valley* detector for the negative half cycles! (Look carefully at the demodulated signal (blue line) from 6 s to 12 s time duration. The message signal is hidden in the valleys not the peaks!)